# Is it possible to print on a file the output of a function?

Tags: file, stdout, output, printf

I'm writing a tool which uses various void functions to analyze some elements that the program receive in input, and print in the stdout (using printf()) the results of the analysis. Obviously that means that i use printf() very much, because there are lots of things that need being printed. I would like that everything is printed on the stdout, is printed also on a log file. But the use of fprintf() for each printf() function makes the program really longer, confused and not well-ordered. Is there a way to save directly the output of a function on a file? So if i have a void function for example analyze() wich contains lots of printf() functions, the output of analyze() will be printed in the stdout (to the shell) and also on a file. I tried to look for it but withouth any results.
Thanks for help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function that will issue a printf and fprintf and call that function instead.

For instance, here's a skeleton, obviously you'll have to fill in the ...:

```
void myPrintf(...) 
{
     printf(...);
     fprintf(...);
}
```

Then in your code, instead of printf, you could call:

```
myPrintf(...);
```

You could also do this with a macro.

If you need to turn off logging, you could do so by simply pulling out the fprintf in that function and leave the rest of your code unchanged.

Comment: In fact this is a great idea! If there's no other solution, like a function the print directly that output of an other function on a file, this is the best i can use! Thanks!! I never thought of.

Comment: However i got a problem. If the printf() function is used also to printf values from various variables and structures...how can i pass them in myPrintf function?
I mean if for example i have a printf like this: 
`printf("The values of x is: %d", x);`

Comment: Do you mean how do you handle a variable number of arguments?

Comment: I mean if for example i have a printf like this: 
`printf("The values of x is: %d", x);`
How can i pass it to myPrintf?

Comment: Ok, for that you need to use varargs.  Check out this link that shows a sample and see if it helps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D

Comment: Thanks now i see what i can do!

Answer (score 1):

It's generally better to have a specialised logging function, rather than peppering your code with direct printf/fprintf calls. That logging function can write to stdout, a log-file, whatever you want, and can be different in debug/release, etc.

Comment: Thanks for answering. How can the logging function being designed? I mean, is it possible to create a specialised logging function that print on a file directly the entire output of an other function? If not, i have to recall it for each printf anyway!